# How to add different vertex attribute values instances in three.js?

Tags: three.js, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I am learning three.js r86 and I want to display a large amount of distorted spheres. To improve performance, I have created an `InstancedBufferGeometry` of spheres in using

```
var cubesGeometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.2, 7, 7));
```

and have successfully positioned multiple spheres using

```
    positions = ... // 3 random float values for each instance
    faPositions = new Float32Array(positions);
    cubesGeometry.addAttribute("pos",new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(faPositions,3,0));
```

with the following vertex shader:

```
  varying vec3 vNormal;
  attribute vec3 pos;
  attribute float displacement;

  void main() {
    vNormal = normalMatrix*normal;
    vec3 newPos = position + normal*vec3(displacement);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPos+pos, 1.0);
  }
```

However, that shader should also provide a random vertex displacement. While the position `pos` is the same for all vertices, the displacement differs between vertices so I cannot use the InstancedBufferAttribute as it would create a uniform sphere. How I can distribute the attribute values so that each vertex gets its own value without it being the same for each instance?.

Comment: Just an idea: Provide an `InstancedBufferAttribute` which provides a "seed" per sphere, and use that seed to generate the distortion effect for that sphere (basically procedural noise generation).

Comment: @TheJim01: But wouldn't the "seed" then be the same at each vertex? Given a deterministic pseudorandom algorithm the output would be the same again. I guess I could combine the seed with the vertex normal.

Comment: Given a sphere, the normals would work to uniquely identify the vertices. It might be easier still to add a standard `BufferAttribute` and give each vertex a unique ID (sort of what `gl_VertexID` would do if it were available).